# Thunderbird: I accept an invitation, but the sender does not see it

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, lightning

I receive an invitation to an event via email.

I use thunderbird and accept the invitation.

I use tine20 for my calendar.

I can see the event in my calendar.

But the sender does not see that I accepted the event.

I have no clue how to debug this.

What could be wrong?

I use thunderbird 52.8.0

AFAIK the sender uses outlook for his calendar.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple email addresses setup in Thunderbird you could be experiencing a problem where the email to accept the invite is being sent using a different address, thus they aren't seeing the accept in their calendar.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1206863

You may also want to try running Thunderbird 60 (newest version) as some of these problems are considered bugs - it's hard to tell if they have been fixed since there is a large chain of duplicates in their bug tracker. ([source](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=475886))

Download for the latest version of Thunderbird is on their [homepage](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) - extracting and running that version should load the same settings as your existing installation. For safety you can package up your current settings in `~/.thunderbird` before using it.

Comment: A team mates uses Thunderbird 60, and he has the same problem: The sender does not see that the invitation was accepted. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer. I am happy that there is progress and Thunderbird gets updates and evolves.